# Word Counter in Python Using Multiple Functions

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a program that I have been assigned that is just getting the word and line count of a sonnet. The first bit of code here works and is the proper output my professor is looking for, even though it includes the first 2 lines of the sonnet.

```
import string


def main():

    ifName = input("What file would you like to analyze? ")
    ofName = input("What file should the results be written to? ")

    infile = open(ifName, "r")
    outfile = open(ofName, "w")

    lineCount = 0
    wordCount = 0

    for line in infile:
        lineCount +=1
        wordLine = line.split()
        L = len(wordLine)
        wordCount += L


    print("The file", ifName, "had:", file= outfile)
    print("words =", wordCount, file= outfile)
    print("lines =", lineCount, file= outfile)
    print("The results have been printed to:", outfile)

    infile.close
    outfile.close

main()
```

However, the next part of the assignment is to get the same results using a second function, "countNum" with the parameter of "line". So countNum(line).

Here is the code I have been messing around with to see if I can get it to work.

```
import string


def countNum(line):
    wordCount = 0
    wordLine = line.split()
    L = len(wordLine)
    wordCount +=L
    print(wordCount)

def main():

    ifName = input("What file would you like to analyze? ")
    ofName = input("What file should the results be written to? ")

    infile = open(ifName, "r")
    outfile = open(ofName, "w")

    lineCount = 0
    wordCount = 0

    for line in infile:
        lineCount +=1
        wordTotal += countNum(line)
        ##wordLine = line.split()
        ##L = len(wordLine)
        ##wordCount += L


  ##  print("The file", ifName, "had:", file= outfile)
  ##  print("words =", wordCount, file= outfile)
  ##  print("lines =", lineCount, file= outfile)
  ##  print("The results have been printed to:", outfile)

    infile.close
    outfile.close

main()
```

If you were wondering, this is the sonnet.txt file:

```
Shakespeare’s Sonnet 18

Shall I compare thee to a summer's day?
Thou art more lovely and more temperate:
Rough winds do shake the darling buds of May,
And summer's lease hath all too short a date:
Sometime too hot the eye of heaven shines,
And often is his gold complexion dimm'd;
And every fair from fair sometime declines,
By chance or nature's changing course untrimm'd;
But thy eternal summer shall not fade
Nor lose possession of that fair thou owest;
Nor shall Death brag thou wander'st in his shade,
When in eternal lines to time thou growest:
So long as men can breathe or eyes can see,
So long lives this, and this gives life to thee.
```

Comment: Are you trying to count the occurrences of each word in a line?

Comment: You would simply need to return wordCount from the function? 'return wordCount'

Comment: you're not really closing your files BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `countNum` is printing the result instead of returning it:

```
def countNum(line):
    return len(line.split())
```

Also, your close methods need to have `()` after them. They aren't actually executing:

```
infile.close
outfile.close
```

to

```
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count(line):
    return len(line.split())

def main():
    infile = open(input("File to analyse: "), "r")
    file = infile.read().splitlines()
    infile.close()

    lineCount = len(file)
    wordTotal = 0

    for line in file:
        words = count(line)

        wordTotal += words

    print("Lines:", lineCount)
    print("Words:", wordTotal)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `len` to get the length of a list. The list of rows is given by `f.readlines()` and the list of words in a line is given by `line.split()`. And we can use the builtin `sum` to sum across a list and be super pythonic
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

You should use Python's automatic closing by using the `with` keyword. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

so we'd have:

```
with open(infilename, "r") as infile, open(outfilename, "w") as outfile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
    linecount = len(lines)
    wordcount = sum([len(line.split()) for line in lines])
    print(linecount)
    print(wordcount)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions for list comprehensions